# Chaincode querying chaincode on separate channels

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have two channels each with a chaincode, channel1 with chaincode1 and channel2 with chaincode2. I am trying to query an asset on channel1 from channel2. Here is a portion of my code from chaincode2

```
return stub.invokeChaincode(CC1, sendArgs, CHANNEL1).then((resp) => {
        console.info(`resp: ${resp}`);
        return shim.success("yay!")
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.info(`Err: ${err}`);
        return shim.error(`Err: ${err}`);
    });
```

From the docker logs I can see this succesfully calls the other chaincode however an error is still returned:  `Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [Err: Error: INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: transaction ID: 665167f6a938d84060ca7e7678e1d36e7e638beee1a359e1ae315f00e315364c: Failed to get policy manager for channel [channel1]]. Sending ERROR message back to peer`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The peer hasn't joined channel1, so it cannot check whether the client is authorized in making this query.

Comment: It is a part of channel1, I have the same peer adding data to channel1